# Matlab crashes using mex-Function and openMP

Tags: c++, matlab, openmp

I have a problem using matlab mexfunction and openMP instructions. I found some related topics but none of them were able to help me.

I want to use openMP with a mex-Function to create a .mexw64 file. But when i use my matlab function, matlab crashes in a brutal way.

Theses are my codes:

C++ code

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs,
    mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs,
    const mxArray *prhs[])

{
    #pragma omp parallel default(shared)
    {

    }
    mexPrintf("Hi !\n");
}
```

Matlab code:

```
clear all, close all, clc;

testopenMP();
clear mex;
```

When i call my function testopenMP matlab crashes. But if I comment the "#pragma omp parallel" instruction, everything work fine:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs,
    mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs,
    const mxArray *prhs[])

{
    //#pragma omp parallel default(shared)
    {

    }
    mexPrintf("Hi !\n");
}
```

Another important point, with the pragma omp parallel intruction, sometimes the program works, and sometimes it crashes...
When i run the program with the deboggeur step by step everythings work fine. I'm really lost

Do you have any ideas of what crashes matlab ? Any help is welcolme

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your mex file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/troubleshoot-mex-files-1.html)?

Comment: Hello, tanks for your interest. I did and this is the error message:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD9273411E in MATLAB.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00007FFD9273411E.

Comment: Your code runs fine in my matlab. So I have to guess that its cause might be specific to your environment.